# How to align divs with different height on top of each other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

You can look at my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SHZ2G/). They have spaces between them, but I want them to be on top of each other. How can I accomplish this with jQuery? I tried using Masonry, but this code didn't help:

```
(function(){
var $container = $('.rss');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 210
  });
});
})();
```

EDIT: Can anyone please make the fiddle work?

Comment: I would use Masonry if I were you, but if you really really don't want to than you need to make a function that can calculate the different sizes of the divs, make them position absolute and calculate where there are space to put them

Comment: Well, the function I used up there didn't work and I don't know what could help. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $(function(){

$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
   isAnimated: true
});
```

});

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aSQAu/2/)**

Comment: I am using max-width and for some reason it makes the container really small instead of the max I set...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the CSS alternative to masonry:

http://sickdesigner.com/masonry-css-getting-awesome-with-css3/

It uses the CSS3 **column-count** property to split the parent container, which means that setting width:100%; to the child containers gets 1 third of the parent width, rather than the full width.

EXAMPLE CSS:

```
.container {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 900px
}
.container div {
    display: inline-block; /* Display inline-block, and absolutely NO FLOATS! */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The demo for this has it set up as a list:

http://sickdesigner.com/demo/css-masonry/css-masonry.html

Here is a fiddle based on your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/SHZ2G/2/

FYI, you can still use masonry for IE compatibility, as mentioned in the above article